# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 Facebook SDK

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook

I'm creating a new tabbed iOS application in xCode 5.1.1. I'm had done research but none of the solutions work to me. So I ended up with migration from xCode 6.1 to xCode 5.1.1. But the problem still occur which I have no idea now. Perhaps the settings in architecture i386 need to be changed. But I have no idea how.

**Error:**

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_ASIdentifierManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdUtility.o)   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CMMotionManager", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in FBAudienceNetwork(FBAdAnalogInfo.o) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command
>   failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

**Build Settings**

> Standard architectures(armv7, armv7s, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)
>
> Build Active Architecture Only : YES / NO

---

**Update:**

After adding CoreMotion and AdSupport frameworks, errors had been reduced. But left one more error which state:

```
missing required architecture x86_64 in file {DIRECTORY}/FacebookSDK/Bolts.framework/Bolts (2 slices)
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppDelegate._window in
```

**Current Framework:**

- CoreMotion
- AdSupport
- CoreGraphics
- FacebookSDK
- UIKit
- FBAudienceNetwork
- Foundation
- Bolts

Answer (score 6):

You need to link

```
AdSupport.framework  
CoreMotion.framework
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution, I still has one error left.

Comment: duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_AppDelegate._window in

Comment: that's another problem, check if _window ivar is double declared, or post the whole error I'll look at

Comment: @ l0gg3r, You are hero, code runs in just 4 seconds.

Answer (score 4):

Did you remove Sample folder after dragging in the FacebookSDK into Frameworks group of your Xcode project? I had the same issue, and it was because Xcode tried to compile all the samples too. Removed Samples folder - everything works as a charm - no need to add AdSupport or any other framework.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't add `AdSupport.framework`.

set property for architecture as below image..

[image]

[image]

Comment: why he should remove all_load flag?

Comment: @user3432164 Thanks for your solution, I still has one error left.

Comment: remove armv64 from your build settings>valid architectures.and make Build Active Architecture Only :NO

Answer (score 0):

Delete Sample Folder. Clean and Build. Will work like a charm.

Comment: Could you explain where is the Sample Folder?

Comment: Can you add more details into why this would fix the original question?

Comment: there is a Sample folder in the Facebook Folder which you need to delete and run. Sample folder contains the sample xcode projects which is for your reference.